# Bilinear forms.

Tags: linear-algebra, solution-verification

Let $V$ be an $\mathbb R$ - vector space and let $V^* = Hom _\mathbb R (V, \mathbb R)$ be the dual space of $V$.

Define $f: V^* \times V \to \mathbb R$ by $$f(l^*, \vec v)=l^*(\vec v) \text{ for all } (l^*, \vec v) \in V^* \times V$$ is a bilinear map. Use the universal mapping property for tensor product to prove that there exists a well-defined linear map $T: V^* \otimes_\mathbb R V \to \mathbb R$ defined by $$ T (c_1l_1^* \otimes \vec v_1+ \dots+c_kl_k^* \otimes \vec v_k)=c_1l_1^*(\vec v_1)+ \dots + c_kl_k^*(\vec v_k)$$ for $c_1,\dots,c_k \in \mathbb R$,    $l_1^*, \dots, l_k^* \in V^*$ and $\vec v_1, \dots, \vec v_k \in V$.

Solution: Given $f: V^* \times V \to \mathbb R$ is a bilinear map. Then by definition of a tensor product, there exists a bilinear map  $\pi: V^* \times V \to V^* \otimes_\mathbb R V$ satisfying the following universal property: Given any bilinear map $f$, there exists a unique linear map $T$ such that $T \circ \pi=f$.  Therefore,  $T: V^* \otimes_\mathbb R V \to \mathbb R $ defined by $ T (c_1l_1^* \otimes \vec v_1+ \dots+c_kl_k^* \otimes \vec v_k)=c_1l_1^*(\vec v_1)+ \dots + c_kl_k^*(\vec v_k)$ for all $c_1,\dots,c_k \in \mathbb R$,    $l_1^*, \dots, l_k^* \in V^*$ and $\vec v_1, \dots, \vec v_k \in V$ exits and is well-defined.

Comment: And the question is ... ?

Comment: @KurtG. it's solution verification

Comment: Reading this bit by bit sounds a bit chatGPT-ish to me. Define $T$ by $T (c_1l_1^* \otimes \vec v_1+ \dots+c_kl_k^* \otimes \vec v_k)=c_1l_1^*(\vec v_1)+ \dots + c_kl_k^*(\vec v_k)$. It is obviously linear and was defined on a basis of $V^* \otimes_\mathbb R V$. This should be all.

Comment: @rumathe thanks! It is a solution verification. Looks like proof follows directly from the definition and the way the problem is set up, it seems like there is nothing to prove. However, I am completing this assignment and wanted to ask the opinions of others.

Comment: Your solution is not clear to me.
Since $f \colon V^* \times V \to \Bbb R$ is bilinear, there is a unique linear map $T \colon V^* \otimes V \to \Bbb R$ such that $T \circ \pi = f$; so $T(l^* \otimes \vec v) = T(\pi(l^*,\vec v)) = f(l^*,\vec v) = l^*(\vec v)$. Then the equation
$$
T(c_1l_1^* \otimes \vec v_1+ \dots+c_kl_k^* \otimes \vec v_k)=c_1l_1^*(\vec v_1)+ \dots + c_kl_k^*(\vec v_k)
$$
follows by the linearity of $T$.

Comment: @KurtG. Thanks!

Comment: @azif00 Thanks!!  I appreciate your response.